# How can I trace out entire GET request from jersey api client call

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I have the following code that calls a http GET request where I map the json result to a specific class of mine called MySpecificJsnoMappedResult.

```
MySpecificJsonMappedResult myResult =   
   jerseyWebResourceClient.path("stuff)
      .queryParam(“param”, “stuff”)
      <lots more query params here>
      .get(MySpecificJsonMappedResult.class);
```

is there an easy way via the jersey client so that can I trace out what the actual http GET call is (with params) in the case (since I'm not using a "ClientResponse" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the [`LoggingFilter`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#d4e740) on the client.

```
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
```

<sup>You're mentioning `ClientResponse`, so I'm guessing you're using Jersey 1. If you're using Jersey 2, you'd use</sup>

```
client.register(new LoggingFilter());
```